# Is it possible to embed pages inside page in Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Assume that there are page 1 and page 2.
Page 1 is server side rendered
Page 2 is Static HTML

What I want to do is embed Page 2 inside Page 1.
Page 1 provide layouts and contextual info about currently logged in user.
Page 2 is actual content will be shown inside Page1's layout.

Is it possible? And can I do that in vice versa? (Embed ServerSideRendered page inside StaticHTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to embed static page (page2) within server side rendered page (page1) and pass the fetched data from page1 to page2 as a props:

```
import Layout from '../path/to/layout'
import Page2 from './path/to/page2'

export default function Page1({data}){

  return(
    <Layout>
    <Page2 data={data}/>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(){
  const response = await fetch('/url/to/json/api')
  const data = response.json()

  return {
    props:{
      data
    }
  }
}
```

However I can't think about the use case for that.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work other way around. If you embed server side render page (page1) into static page (page2) the getServerSideProps function won't get fired, and data object will remain undefined.

Comment: How about vice versa? Embed SSR page inside StaticPage? For example, blog's post are static rendered for proxy caching but also contains comments about the post. Since comments are flexible, can be added at any time, I think it should be SSR. It is exact features with this StackOverflow question page, my answer and your post are Static Rendered and this comment i'm writing on is SSR maybe? or assume that?

Comment: Sticking to your example I guess that what you need is `/api` route. Next `/api` routes are special server side rendered functions, where you can fetch some data and return it, for example to your static page. Let's say you have /blog static page where you use `useEffect(()=>fetch('/api/posts').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>console.log(data))`. That way you are able to consume the recived data (ssr rendered) within your static `/blog` page. Read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Comment: It seems what I'm looking for. Very appreciate, I'll try and leave some answer to here. Thanks :)